# get_posts with meta_compare='LIKE' not working

Tags: get-posts

I am using the following code:

```
$tolettpe = "Sale";//default
if($_REQUEST['tolettype']) $tolettpe = $_REQUEST['tolettype'];
else if($_REQUEST['srch_type']) $tolettpe = $_REQUEST['srch_type'];
$args = array(
    'numberposts'  => $latestcount,
    'category'     => $catidstr,
  'meta_key'     => 'property_type',
  'meta_compare' => 'LIKE',
  'meta_value'   => $tolettpe.'%'
 );
$post_content = get_posts($args);
```

The value in the database is 'Sale||' and there are no query string variables in the request.

But the query returns no results.

If I use the exact value and no meta_compare, it works.

Any ideas how to make this work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`meta_compare` Possible values are `'!=', '>', '>=', '<', or '<='`. Default value is `'='`

if you want to use `LIKE` you need to create a meta_query eg:

```
$tolettpe = "Sale";//default
if($_REQUEST['tolettype']) $tolettpe = $_REQUEST['tolettype'];
else if($_REQUEST['srch_type']) $tolettpe = $_REQUEST['srch_type'];
$args = array(
    'numberposts'  => $latestcount,
    'category'     => $catidstr,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'property_type',
            'value' => $tolettpe,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
);
$posts = get_posts($args);
```

The generated query puts the search term between two % signs, so there is no need to add any in the code.

Comment: thanks, i've tried it but am not getting any results returned. Is there any way to print out the query being generated so I can run it directly in the database to debug?

Comment: ok, found the answer to that one http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Save_queries_for_analysis

Comment: actually my original method works as well, the extra % sign was the problem!